# How do I play a RTMP stream in VLC?

Tags: streaming, vlc-media-player, video-streaming, rtmp

I'm trying to get a RTMP stream to play on VLC and the URL is in this format:
`rtmp://76.10.10.240/liverepeater/mp4:name.mp4`

I'm able to record the stream with CooJah but I only want to watch it via VLC. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try asking on #videolan on freenode?

Comment: @Akash No, I didn't

Comment: Do try it out..  you are more likely to get help on the IRC/forums/mailing list

Comment: The KMplayer plays rtmp streams ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can play RTMP in VLC with the help of RTMPDump .

```
rtmpdump -v -r "rtmp://ip-address/app-name/streamname" -o - | "vlc" -
```

Comment: I'll check it out...

Comment: Check and let me know...

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Now you can do it in VLC. Because the new versions of VLC from v1.1 onwards support rtmp stream playing.

1. Just Click on Media.
2. Click on open network stream / or press Ctrl/command + N
3. Write rtmp URL.
4. Enjoy!

Comment: No, its not playing, it throws stream not found error!

Comment: no it won't work

Comment: it only works with some rtmp streams

Comment: why VLC asks me to open accessibility on Mac? It feels so dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but VLC doesn't support rtmp streaming just yet. If you really want to stream RTMP, you could use flowplayer since they support it, but it's not as easy as using VLC.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac/OSX, I was able to get this to work with a modification of Unnikrishnan's answer. The important part being the path to the VLC executable (which may vary by system)

Recorded Stream:

`rtmpdump -r rtmp://path/to/stream | /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -`

Live stream

`rtmpdump -r rtmp://path/to/stream --live | /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -`

You should then see a VLC window open, with `fs://0` listed in the playlist area. Double-click that entry to view the actual stream.

Comment: I've tried **rtmpdump -r rtmp://path/to/stream --live -o | "c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"** on windows 8.1 but it seems it does not work, any idea ?

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui My approach is using the OSX terminal, so I'm not sure it would work properly in Windows. In Windows 10, there is a new ability to install a "native" Bash prompt, which also [supports calling Windows executables](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/19/interop-between-windows-and-bash/)

Answer (score 1):

VLC version 2.2.4 can play, Hit Cmd+N (on MAC) and enter the url in this format

rtmp://Server URL/live/Stream Name

e.g
rtmp://10.154.136.221/live/RTMP1

Comment: This information solved my `<playpath>` problem. I converted my rtmp link `rtmp://streaming.perculus.com/vods3<playpath>flv:blabla.flv` to `rtmp://streaming.perculus.com/vods3/live/flv:blabla.flv` Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mplayer or at least rtmpdump from mplayer as vlc has no rtmp support currently.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that you have to add the port number as well

> rtmp://192.168.18.26:1935/live/stream

where 192.168.18.26 is your localhost / IP

[There](https://github.com/ustoopia/Live-stream-server-portable-Windows-Nginx-RTMP-HLS-Dash) is an excellent tutorial on RTMP streaming using OBS and HLS client using Nginx server.